# Методы использующие Context в произвольных классах

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Изучаю Android разработку и столкнулся с вопросом. Допустим я создаю произвольных класс и там мне нужно вызвать метов требующий **Contex**t (или в параметры мне нужно передать **Activity**). Например, я создаю **View** элемент, допустим **Button**, и я не смогу использовать метод **findViewById**. Что делать в таких ситуациях? Разумно ли в конструктор этого класса передавать **Context**?

Comment: передача необходимых объектов через конструктор (если это возможно) это лучший из вариантов

Comment: Потом всегда надо делать Context null`ом? Чтобы избежать утечку памяти

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите. Тут стоит разделить эти классы на несколько категорий.

- Классы, наследующие `View` или `VuewGroup`. Эти классы уже хранят в себе ссылку на `Context`. Туда ничего прокидывать не надо. Точнее там `Context` по дефолту должен быть в конструкторе. И использование там контекста легетимно и вполне нормально.
- Классы которые требуют для работы контекст(Например `SQLite`). Для этих классов зачастую достаточно [Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-in-android).  **Application Context** не влечет за собой риска Memory Leak и его использовать вполне безопасно.
- Во всех остальных случаях, нужно стараться избегать использовать `Context`. Во-первых передача контекста `Activity` влечет за собой риск утечек памяти. Во-вторых классы которые хранят в себе `Context` сложно тестировать. Но это не значит, что этого делать нельзя. Иногда можно и даже нужно, но всегда нужно позаботиться о том, чтоб при уничтожении `Activity` очищалась и ссылка на нее.